# LIUM Speaker Diarization throws "FileNotFoundException: showName.mfcc"

Tags: java, speech-recognition, filenotfoundexception, mfcc

I am attempting to use the LIUM Speaker Diarization tool, which works on Java, but on Windows 10, the execution of the line :

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar /mnt/c/Users/LIUM_SpkDiarization-8.4.1.jar \ --fInputMask= /mnt/c/Users/showName.wav --sOutputMask= /mnt/c/Users/showName.seg –doCEClustering showName
```

throws the following exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: showName.mfcc (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JS_MP3FileReader.getAudioFileFormat(JS_MP3FileReader.java:82)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(AudioSystem.java:1070)
    at fr.lium.spkDiarization.libFeature.AudioFeatureSetFactory.getAudio(AudioFeatureSetFactory.java:162)
    at fr.lium.spkDiarization.libFeature.AudioFeatureSetFactory.MakeFeature(AudioFeatureSetFactory.java:207)
    at fr.lium.spkDiarization.libFeature.AudioFeatureSetFactory.MakeMFCCFeature(AudioFeatureSetFactory.java:255)
    at fr.lium.spkDiarization.libFeature.AudioFeatureSet.read(AudioFeatureSet.java:898)
    at fr.lium.spkDiarization.libFeature.AudioFeatureSet.setCurrentShow(AudioFeatureSet.java:1322)
    at fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Diarization.ester2Diarization(Diarization.java:719)
    at fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Diarization.run(Diarization.java:634)
```

I have run it on Linux as well but the same exception is thrown.

I am quite at a loss as to why it does not work. From what I understood, the program takes a .wav as an input and outputs a .seg file. Therefore, why does it search for a .mfcc file which it supposedly has to compute itself ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have extra spaces and wrong backslash in your command line. If yo use proper command line it should be ok.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayShmyrev ! It works fine now.